# AppConKit 3: How do I enable the device log view?

Tags: appconkit

Currently, I am developing an App using the AppConKit 3. In the debug perspective of the IDE, there is a view at the bottom called "Device Log". It is supposed to display log messages generated by the mobile device. There are two fields to input an URL and a port and a "Connect" button. I'm not sure which settings to use, the default settings 127.0.0.1 with port 4012 did not work for me - I couldn't see any log messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the log view, you have to enable the log server in your app's server part. Switch to the Java perspective, unfold the "WebContent" area and also the "WEB-INF". In there, you should find the `ibiz.prop` file. In that file, uncomment the two lines

```
#the port the remote device connects to
devicelogport            = 4000
#the port the remote UI connects to 
guilogport                = 4012
```

When you now restart your app (server), you should be able to connect to the device log server and see log messages.